# Is it possible to "freeze" a GlobalPlatform smartcard?

Tags: smartcard, javacard, globalplatform

In a smartcard implementing GlobalPlatform, is there a way for the issuer to irrevocably yield its card management capabilities in a way that leaves all currently installed and selectable applications in a working state, but does not allow any life cycle changes or installation of additional applications?

The GlobalPlatform specification does not seem to give any concrete guidance. There is a way to delete keys, but it's unclear whether it would be possible to delete an active card management key from the description.

One [anecdotal example](https://www.yubico.com/2016/05/secure-hardware-vs-open-source/) that I've found states that a certain hardware token (conforming to GlobalPlatform) is shipped with a randomized card management key. However, this might not be due to limitations of a given card implementation but rather to allow for future secure application updates.

Comment: Good question. I've seen vendors that limit all or some CCM operations once the card leaves the factory, but they use the same GP card state (SECURED) as other vendors that allow the same operations.
I think it is enforced at OS level, not following any GP state description.

Answer (score 2):

If you dont have the keys, you cant do updates, so the randomized key is a practical solution. But it is a procedure/organizational feature rather than a standardized Technical feature. Your chip might also have proprietary “permanent fusing” feature as well (ccheck your vendor)